# how can I call variable out side of $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, forms, hide

I am trying to make condition to call chain function in Jquery. I used $.ajax in Jquery submit function to get values from login.php and I am trying to call fadeOut function to close login form. If login succes form will close then there will be some Success  message and then it wil lalso close. And if error then form will remain and also error message. 
I made it also but  in my login.js  when I call $('.loginform').fadeOut(1000) it works also if  login succes or not.

```
jQuery('#login').live('submit',function(event) {

$.ajax({
    url: 'lib/login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $('#login').serialize(),
    success: function( data ) {

       for(var id in data) {
            jQuery('.' + id).html(data[id]);    
        }
$('.loginform').hide(1000);     

    }
 });

return false;
 }
```

});

and my login.php file  includes

```
if(result==1){
  $arr = array ( "loginOK" => "Success." ); 

} else {

 $arr = array ( "errors" => "Please try again ." );

}
echo json_encode( $arr );
```

this is index.html

```
    <!--Login Form tag -->

<div class='errors'></div>

 <div class='loginOK'></div>

<div class='loginform'>

  <form  action ="" method="post" id="login">
    <fieldset class="loginfield">
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="username">User Name</label> <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" id="submit-go" ></button>
<a href="#?w=500" rel="popup_name" class="poplight">Sing up</a>

</form>

</div>
```

Comment: why do you use `$` and `jQuery` I would use only one of them for consistency, because `$` is an alias for `jQuery`, I only use `jQuery` if the `$` is used by something other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `success: function( data ) {` handler executes when the request is successful, not when the login is successful. You need to provide a flag in your `json` to indicate that, and check that flag it in your handler:

```
success: function( data ) {

    if(data.success) {
       for(var id in data) {
           jQuery('.' + id).html(data[id]);    
       }
       $('.loginform').hide(1000);   

    }  else {
       alert('Error logging in');
    }

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Your current json object is like

```
{
  id_1:'html_1',
  id_2:'html_2'
}
```

You should make it something like

```
{
  html: {
    id_1: 'html_1',
    id_2: 'html_2'
  },
  success: $login_success
}
```

Comment: this flag must be in $.ajax  ?

Comment: is json object will be like $flag= true ;  and in jqury   if (flag){$('.loginform').hide(1000);}else{alert('Error logging in');}  ???